# Handling rejected ajax request?

Tags: angularjs

I have created a simple test program that fetches  a json result for each number which I have in an array.

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, utils, $sce, $q)
{
    var numbers = [85 , 84, 85 ];
    var ctrl = this;
    var arr = [];
    var arr2 = [];
    angular.forEach(numbers, function(v, k)
    {
        arr.push(utils.getPosts('http://b1estvision.co.il/poligon/wp-json/wp/v2/media/' + (v)));
    });
    $q.all(arr).then(function(b)
    {
        angular.forEach(b, function(v, k)
        {
            arr2.push(v.data.source_url)
        })
        ctrl.pics = arr2;
    });
});
```

So for each number in `[85 , 84, 85 ]` , I fetch a json which has am IMG url within it.

Using `$q.all` I wait for *all* jsons to be downloaded , and then I try to read the value of the ing url and put it in the screen (`ctrl.pics`) via `ng-repeat`.

It works great :

[image]

But if I modify this array :

```
  var numbers = [85 , 84, 85 ];
```

to

```
 var numbers = [85 , 0,85  ]; // second request will not be resolved because of "NOT FOUND".
```

— It won't show me nothing ( because of a rejected request)

Goal : I want to put a default image   *only* for the request which was rejected ( say this : http://dummyimage.com/130x40.png/09f/fff/&text=not%20found)

**Question**

How can I modify my code so that I can put a default image for rejected promise/s .

[**FULL PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/JAAmfKeZhikPUS8DlfGJ?p=preview)

The order is important ! Each img in html should match the order of array of numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your `getPost` return a promise which always have a default data:

```
     getPosts: function(address){
       return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
            $http({
              method: 'GET',
              url: address
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
              resolve(response);
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
              resolve({
                data:{
                  "source_url": "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mazenl77/I-like-buttons-3a/512/Cute-Ball-Go-icon.png"
                }
              });
            });
        });
      }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/sGnFpJH8lZ4gnLI568OR?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution to your problem:

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, utils, $sce, $q) {
  var numbers = [85, 85, 0];
  var ctrl = this;
  ctrl.pics = [];
  
  angular.forEach(numbers, function(v, k) {
    utils.getPosts('http://bestvision.co.il/poligon/wp-json/wp/v2/media/' + (v)).then(
      function(v) { //success
        ctrl.pics[k] = v.data.source_url;
      },
      function() { //error
        ctrl.pics[k] = 'http://dummyimage.com/130x40.png/09f/fff/&text=not%20found';
      }
    );
  });

 
});
```

Q.all will fail if any of the promises in the array fails, see https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference:

> **promise.all()**
>
> Returns a promise that is fulfilled with an array containing the fulfillment value of each promise, or is rejected with the same rejection reason as the first promise to be rejected.

[Forked plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yg8y91lLfOp2lGbc5eFc?p=preview)

Comment: This wont maintain the order

Comment: I have updated my answer to maintain the order. It now uses the k index instead of pushing the url into the array.